# ACTUALIZAR TABLA ORACLE

Tags: oracle, update

Crear un update a partir de esta select.

```
SELECT TP.COD_TP, TPF.COD_TF, TP.CAMPO, TPF.CAMPO 
FROM TABLA_PRINCIPAL TP, TABLA_PRINCIPAL_FINAL TPF
WHERE TP.COD_TP = TPF.COD_TP 
AND TP.CAMPO = 9 AND TPF.CAMPO != 9;
```

Explico con mas detalle:

En la select a través del `cod_tp` de dos tablas compruebo que el valor de `CAMPO` en una sea `9` y en la otra no, el `UPDATE` que necesito es para que en los valores de `CAMPO` que **NO** sea `9` cuando en la `TABLA_PRINCIPAL` **SI** que sea `9` entonces se tiene que actualizar a `9` en la `TABLA_PRINCIPAL_FINAL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer esto:

```
UPDATE TABLA_PRINCIPAL_FINAL SET CAMPO = 9
WHERE COD_TF IN (
    SELECT TPF.COD_TF
    FROM TABLA_PRINCIPAL TP, TABLA_PRINCIPAL_FINAL TPF
    WHERE TP.COD_TP = TPF.COD_TF AND TP.CAMPO = 9 AND TPF.CAMPO != 9
);
```

Comment: Perfecto! Me ha actualizado bien los registros que había que actualizar!
Muchísimas gracias Marc!